# scheduling and access control to serial port in multi thread C program

Tags: c, multithreading, serial-port

Serial port open to the public and a thread always works with the port.
One or more high priority thread are created at run-time witch without Conflict with the main thread should work with the port and destroy when completed.
how can i schedule these threads and manage access to serial port?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are creating many threads and you always want only one thread to work with the serial port (one thread at a time), you can manage it's access through the use of semaphores (so that they do not collide).

However the scheduling algorithm which you want to use **purely depends on your need**. When you are creating more than one thread I am sure you must be using `pthread_create` API which has more flexibility to set your attributes (such as priority) in it's second parameter. Please use that parameter to set you priority levels. You can schedule them by taking their priorities into consideration or you can even use a time slice technique.

When analyzing your question it looks like you are working on some development board. In case it is an RTOS code, you can try implementing the preemption mechanism along with semaphores.